# Mock Exe using another name

Tags: c#, process, window, exe

I have an exe called as mct.exe

One of the existing c# application check for the instance of mct.exe every time and if the instance is zero it will trigger the exe and if there is any mct.exe already running it will not trigger the exe i.e no more than one mct.exe will run at a given time. This is because mct.exe will occupy high cpu usage and if there are several instances of mct.exe running for long time than system might become irresponsive.

Now, I need to use the same mct.exe for another application on same server and I cannot edit the existing application to check two instances of mct.exe . So is there any possibility that I can mock mct.exe as another exe named mockmct.exe and use mockmct.exe for my second application?

I also understand mockmct.exe will also occupy same amount cpu that mct.exe does but that is ok.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question. However, if you do rename the executable and run it, it will appear with the renamed executable name in the process list. Note that the config file will need a similar rename.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just stop the watchdog as the most trivial solution?
Now, if you cannot, is it running as an administrator? If not then it should check only the processes of the current user - so you can run your second mct.exe as another user and it should be invisible to the watchdog...

Comment: I need to run both the applications on same user account